# Rename WSUS computer groups

Tags: wsus

Is there a tool (command line or GUI) to rename the computer groups in WSUS?  The WSUS management console can create and delete groups, but not rename them.

Comment: How are the computers registering themselves? Do you manually assign computers to groups, or are you using GPO to do this?

Comment: @MDMarra - Computers are being manually registered.  Group Policy is not involved.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the only way to rename a group is to do it directly in the WSUS database (or possibly through an API).  Otherwise "renaming" involves creating new groups and changing the membership of the computers.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way to do it. Directly in the database and make sure the WSUS service AND the IIS site are stopped while doing this.